# TicTacToe AI - Computer Winning move java

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence

is there a way of getting the winning move for AI on TicTacToe using for loop. So checking if any two buttons next to each other have the value X or O then make the third make the same value to make the AI win.

Using a for loop to go through array of 3 by 3 buttons and checking if any two buttons next to each other has the same value.

I have tried this but not sure if its correct because it isn;t working the computer doesn't make any winning move.

Comment: Have you looked at an algorithm called Alpha Beta Pruning? If not, it's a great way to implement an AI tic-tac-toe player

Comment: @AlejandroLucena, nope, I never came across this algorithm but I will look it up now.

Answer (score 0):

For easier understanding, you could make multiple loops for row/column/diagonal each:
Count X or O in one row/column/diagonal, if it equals 2, add the third one in the remaining field (if it is empty)

There are MANY ways to accomplish what you want. You could even bruteforce every possible move, count the winning results and chose the one with the most possibilities.

Another easy way would be to write a method which will check for every field if it blocks an opponent winning move and/or results in a winning move for oneself.

Comment: @bleed182, previously, I had made bunch of if and else if statements but what I understand for loops are better but I am finding it hard to turn my if and else ifs into for loops.

Comment: would be best to start with an easier programming task if you feel unsure, even simple AI isn't the easiest thing to achieve without experience

Comment: I done a AI which is hard coded, so checking for all the possible winning moves using if and else if statements and that works fine but the code for that is very large and messy, therefore I am trying to use for loops to check winning moves but my attempts isn;t working.

Answer (score 0):

A common A.I. algorithm in gaming is [The Min/Max Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) Basically, a player looks ahead to evaluate the state of the game resulting from every possible sequence of events, and chooses the move such as to maximize their chances of winning.

For tic-tac-toe you may want to consider starting with a player and looking at all of the possible child states that could follow a given state. You could evaluate some score such as whether the move leads you to a state where you have 2 x's lined up. You then propagate this score up your tree, so the current player has an informed decision to make.'

Min-max assumes your opponent is playing perfectly, so you can sometimes encounter problems there.

For a good description of A.I. and the tic-tac-toe problem check out [Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu) Chapter 5, adversarial search, covers gaming and specifically refers to tic-tac-toe.